# Find $x \in \mathbb{Q}(i)$ with $ |x - 1|_{2+i} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} $, $|x+1|_{2-i} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$ and $|x|_{7} < \frac{1}{7} $

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, absolute-value, chinese-remainder-theorem, adeles

I wanted to try some examples with adeles and strong aproximation.  Let $\mathfrak{p}_1 = 2+i$ and $\mathfrak{p}_2 = 2-i$ and $\mathfrak{p}_3 = 7$.  Can we a single number $x \in \mathbb{Q}(i)$ that's close to all these numbers?

$$ |x - 1|_{\mathfrak{p}_1} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \text{ and } |x+1|_{\mathfrak{p}_2} <  \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \text{ and } |x|_{\mathfrak{p}_3} < \frac{1}{7} $$

I think the $p$-adic valuations make sense.  Since $5 = (2+i) \times (2-i)$ so that we could have a [valuation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84384/extending-the-p-adic-valuation?rq=1) with $|5| = \frac{1}{5}$ and that $|2 \pm i| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$.